# Go-lang parallel segment runs slower than series segment

Tags: go, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have built an epidemic mathematics model which is fairly computationally intense in Go. I'm trying now to build a set of systems to test my model, where I change an input and expect a different output. I built a version in series to slowly increase HIV prevalence and see effects on HIV deaths. It takes ~200 milliseconds to run.

```
for q = 0.0; q < 1000; q++ {

    inputs.CountryProfile.HivPrevalenceAdultsByGroup[0] = inputs.CountryProfile.HivPrevalenceAdultsByGroup[0] * float32(math.Pow(1.00001, q))
    results := costAnalysisHandler(inputs)
    fmt.Println(results.HivDeaths[20])

}
```

Then I made a "parallel" version using channels, and it takes **longer**, ~400 milliseconds to run. These small changes are important as we will be running millions of runs with different inputs, so would like to make it as efficient as possible. Here is the parallel version:

```
ch := make(chan ChData)
var q float64
for q = 0.0; q < 1000; q++ {
    go func(q float64, inputs *costanalysis.Inputs, ch chan ChData) {
        inputs.CountryProfile.HivPrevalenceAdultsByGroup[0] = inputs.CountryProfile.HivPrevalenceAdultsByGroup[0] * float32(math.Pow(1.00001, q))
        results := costAnalysisHandler(inputs)
        fmt.Println(results.HivDeaths[20])
        ch <- ChData{int(q), results.HivDeaths[20]}
    }(q, inputs, ch)
}
for q = 0.0; q < 1000; q++ {
    theResults := <-ch
    fmt.Println(theResults)
}
```

Any thoughts are **very much** appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's overhead to starting and communicating with background tasks. The time spent on your cost analyses <strike>probably dwarfs</strike> equals the cost of communication if the program was taking 200ms, but if coordination cost ever *does* kill your app, a common approach is to hand off largish chunks of work at a time--e.g., make each goroutine do analyses for a range of 10 `q` values instead of just one. (Edit: And as @Innominate says, making a "worker pool" of goroutines that process a queue of job objects is another common approach.)

Also, the code you pasted has a race condition. The contents of your `Inputs` struct don't get copied each time you spawn a goroutine, because you're passing your function a *pointer*. So goroutines running in parallel will read from and write to the same `Inputs` instance.

Simply making a brand new `Inputs` instance for each analysis, with its own arrays, etc. would avoid the race. If that ended up wasting tons of memory or causing lots of redundant copies, you could 1) [recycle `Inputs` instances](http://blog.cloudflare.com/recycling-memory-buffers-in-go), 2) separate out read-only data that can safely be shared (maybe there's country data that's fixed, dunno), or 3) change some of the relatively big arrays to be local variables within `costAnalysisHandler` rather than stuff that needs to be passed around (maybe it could just take initial HIV prevalence and return HIV deaths at t=20, and everything else is local and on the stack).

This doesn't apply to Go today, but did when the question was originally posted: nothing is really running in parallel unless you call `runtime.GOMAXPROCS()` with your desired concurrency level, e.g., `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())`.

Finally, you should only worry about all of this if you're doing some larger analysis and actually have a performance problem; if .2 seconds of waiting is all that performance work can save you here, it's not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Parallelizing a computationally intensive set of calculations requires that the parallel computations can actually run in parallel on your machine. If they don't then the extra overhead of creating goroutines, channels and reading off the channel will make the program run slower.

I'm guessing that is the problem here.

Try setting the GOMAXPROCS environment variable to the number of CPU's you have before running your code. Or call runtime.GOMAXRPROCS(runtime.NumCPU()) before you start the parallell computations.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues related to parallel performance,

The first and more obvious one is that you must set GOMAXPROCS in order to get the Go runtime to use more than one cpu/core. Typically one would set it for the number of processors in the machine but the ideal setting can vary.

The second problem is a bit trickier, which is that your code doesn't appear to be parallelizing very well.  Simply starting a thousand goroutines and assuming they'll work it out isn't going to give good results. You should probably be using some kind of worker pool, running a limited number of simultaneous computations(a good starting number would be to set it the same as GOMAXPROCS) rather than trying to do 1000 at once.

See: http://golang.org/doc/faq#Why_no_multi_CPU