# Worse performance when using go routines in parallel quicksort implementation

Tags: concurrency, go, parallel-processing, quicksort, goroutine

Note: The "Go-lang parallel segment runs slower than series segment" question dealt with race conditions, this one has another issue, so imho it's not a duplicate.

I'm trying to find an explanation for the following situation:
Running parallel quicksort results in a significantly longer runtime when done using go routines.

Benchmarks are after the code:

```
package c9sort

import (
    "time"
)

var runInParllel bool

func Quicksort(nums []int, parallel bool) ([]int, int) {
    started := time.Now()
    ch := make(chan int)
    runInParllel = parallel

    go quicksort(nums, ch)

    sorted := make([]int, len(nums))
    i := 0
    for next := range ch {
        sorted[i] = next
        i++
    }
    return sorted, int(time.Since(started).Nanoseconds() / 1000000)
}

func quicksort(nums []int, ch chan int) {

    // Choose first number as pivot
    pivot := nums[0]

    // Prepare secondary slices
    smallerThanPivot := make([]int, 0)
    largerThanPivot := make([]int, 0)

    // Slice except pivot
    nums = nums[1:]

    // Go over slice and sort
    for _, i := range nums {
        switch {
        case i <= pivot:
            smallerThanPivot = append(smallerThanPivot, i)
        case i > pivot:
            largerThanPivot = append(largerThanPivot, i)
        }
    }

    var ch1 chan int
    var ch2 chan int

    // Now do the same for the two slices
    if len(smallerThanPivot) > 1 {
        ch1 = make(chan int, len(smallerThanPivot))
        if runInParllel {
            go quicksort(smallerThanPivot, ch1)
        } else {
            quicksort(smallerThanPivot, ch1)
        }
    }
    if len(largerThanPivot) > 1 {
        ch2 = make(chan int, len(largerThanPivot))
        if runInParllel {
            go quicksort(largerThanPivot, ch2)
        } else {
            quicksort(largerThanPivot, ch2)
        }
    }

    // Wait until the sorting finishes for the smaller slice
    if len(smallerThanPivot) > 1 {
        for i := range ch1 {
            ch <- i
        }
    } else if len(smallerThanPivot) == 1 {
        ch <- smallerThanPivot[0]
    }
    ch <- pivot

    if len(largerThanPivot) > 1 {
        for i := range ch2 {
            ch <- i
        }
    } else if len(largerThanPivot) == 1 {
        ch <- largerThanPivot[0]
    }

    close(ch)
}
```

Benchmarks for a random perm of 500000 integers:

Ran 100 times

Non parallel average - 1866ms

Parallel average - 2437ms

Any explanation would be appreciated. I know goroutines may not be best for this kind of parallelism, but I'm trying to understand the reason.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Go-lang parallel segment runs slower than series segment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670242/go-lang-parallel-segment-runs-slower-than-series-segment)

Comment: There're clearly similarities, but (after writing an accepted answer on the other q!) I'm not sure it's a dupe, because the fix looks pretty different for a recursive thing like quicksort as opposed to the flat "do some analysis on every item in an array" task.

Comment: What's your GOMAXPROCS?

Comment: Posted a strategy, hope to flesh it out with sample code when I get time. (I'd like to start with a minimal serial `qsort` for clarity, so it'll take a little time to do that.)

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/ncw/5419af0e255d2fb62b98) is a parallel quicksort I wrote just for fun which abuses go concurrency mechanisms...

Comment: FYI, it's best to do benchmarking of Go code with the [benchmarking support in the `testing` package](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks). Then you and others can easily do `go test -bench=. -cpu=1,4,8` (or whatever number of CPUs is appropriate).

Comment: @dmitri-goldring I used your comment and checked the number of GOMAXPROCS, I posted the answer as such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was very simple. As I'm on a new machine, the GOMAXPROCS variable wasn't set.

The new benchmark favors, as predicted, the parallel implementation:
Set to double the number of cores:

```
Using 16 goroutines
Ran 100 times

Non parallel average - 1980
Parallel average - 1133
```

Set to the number of cores:

```
Using 8 goroutines
Ran 100 times

Non parallel average - 2004
Parallel average - 1197
```

By the way, this is fairly consistent. The average for double the number of cores is always a bit better.

Benchmark for a larger collection (1000000):

```
Using 8 goroutines
Ran 100 times

Non parallel average - 3748
Parallel average - 2265
```

With double:

```
Using 16 goroutines
Ran 100 times

Non parallel average - 3817
Parallel average - 2012
```

Comment: You don't just want to [blindly always set GOMAXPROCS](https://golang.org/doc/faq#Why_GOMAXPROCS). Set it as appropriate per program, or for some programs it may be appropriate to use [`runtime.GOMAXPROCS()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS) (possibly via a `-cpu` or `-ncpu` flag of your program).

Comment: I'm not sure I agree, as "This call will go away when the scheduler improves" [runtime.GOMAXPROCS()](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS). In any case, the point was that the default has no value at all.

Answer (score 6):

The general answer is that inter-thread coordination has a cost, so sending a task off to another goroutine can only speed things up if the task is at least a certain size. So don't send single items.

For a divide-and-conquer algorithm like quicksort, the ways to parallelize can be interesting. Generally: when you recurse, you can start the "sort one half of the array" task in a goroutine if it's large enough. The "if it's large enough" part is how you reduce coordination overhead.

In more detail, that looks like:

1. write a non-parallel `qsort(data []int)`
2. change `qsort` to optionally take a [`*sync.WaitGroup`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) we'll call `wg` for signaling that it's done. Add `if wg != nil { wg.Done() }` before each of its `return`s.
3. where `qsort` recurses, have it check whether the half of the data it's going to sort is large-ish (say, over 500 items?), and

   - if it's large, start another task: `wg.Add(1); go qsort(half, wg)`
   - if it's not, sort here and now: `qsort(half, nil)`
4. wrap `qsort` in to hide the parallel machinery from the user: like, have `quicksort(data)` do `wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)`, do an initial `wg.Add(1)`, call `qsort(data, wg)`, and do `wg.Wait()` to wait for all of the background sorts to complete.

This isn't an *optimal* strategy, because it keeps forking off new goroutines even after there are enough tasks to keep your cores busy. And there is a lot of tuning one could do around just *how* you hand off some tasks to the background. But the big point is, using another thread *only for large subtasks* is a way to parallelize quicksort without getting smashed by coordination overhead.

Here's a [demo with an embarrassingly slapdash quicksort](http://play.golang.org/p/QMQxKEzATq) (you have run it locally to get the timing)--good chance of bugs, definitely is quadratic on already-sorted data; the point is to get the idea of parallel divide-and-conquer across.

There is also a bottom-up strategy--sort pieces then merge--used in, for instance, [this parallel sort package](https://github.com/Workiva/go-datastructures/blob/master/sort/sort.go). The in-place merge code that package uses is tricky, though.

(And if you haven't set GOMAXPROCS, set it with something like `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())` in `main`.)

Finally, [look at Go's sort package](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/sort/). There's a lot of code, but it's pretty clear, and once you get it you can do your experiments with a "real", fleshed-out sort implementation.

Comment: After checking everything, the reason was simple enough and not in the algorithm itself. Additionally, the reason I'm not using the sort package is that I'm giving a Go course, and this is one of the challenges. I wanted to understand the issue for the class.